# Kendo grid group header customize to show the value and more

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a Kendo grid that is groupable.  The initial display needs to show all data items with no groupings displayed, i.e no 'group' and 'groupHeaderTemplate' are defined.

The grid contains a column (Suspension) where the value displayed is a translated dataitem value, i.e. if value > 10, display '*'.

When the user drags the Suspension column header cell to group, how can you customize the group header to show the value that it is grouping on plus the display 'value', i.e. 10-* ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean on the button to turn off the group, or the group header text above each group in the grid ?

If the button to remove the grouping, I think you are stuck doing that manually.

If you mean the text above each group, columns have a groupHeaderTemplate property you can set.

```
groupHeaderTemplate: "Grouped By Name: #= value #"
```

See sample http://jsbin.com/IbITaT/2/edit

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It is the group header text above each group.  However, in your code, instead of 'Age:21' or 'Age:31', etc., I want it to display 'Age:21 xxx' - where xxx is some custom text based on the passed value of 21.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Then instead of an inline template, make a function call and you can do pretty much whatever you need.  http://jsbin.com/IbITaT/3/edit

Comment: Thanks.  I will play with it.